# Match Separate Array Values & Print Results

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
// Setup Query
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM here');

// Pull in the appropriate data for the model
$toolkitName = $this->toolkits_model->find_by('id', $id);

// Strip the commas from incoming array
$matchMeCommas = $toolkitName->toolkits_listitems; 
$matchMe = explode(',', $matchMeCommas);    

// Print ID for each item in toolkit parent list
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) :
echo $row['id'];
endforeach;

// Match each item from toolkit list item
foreach ($matchMe as $row2) :
echo $row2;
endforeach;
```

What I'm trying to do is match the values from these two arrays and print the results from the parent list item. Currently what happens is that I get two strings of "234567891011" which relates to the ID (2, 3, 4, 5, ect).

I should add that I would want to match like values and pull results for that specific ID. So if the values 2 & 4 match I would want to retrieve their information from the DB and print it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If the values match *how*?

Comment: On what criteria would 2 & 4 match ... in your code above, I'm only seeing ids and I don't see where you've attempted to match anything ...

Comment: If they match equally. 2 = 2 or 4 = 4.

Comment: I'm not sure how to match the two, so there is no code for that. I tried putting one of the foreach statements inside another, but it threw back and error. The idea would be to match $row2 = $row['id']

Comment: Are you looking for matching array keys, or matching array values?

Comment: I'm looking to match the array values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not exactly sure what you want, but this could get you started:

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    if(in_array($row['id'], $matchMe)){
        //this is a match ... do something
    }
}
```

OR

You could build an array of all matches:

```
//get the ids from the query
$ids = array();
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}

$matches = array_intersect($matchMe, $ids);
```